# How to count the occurrences of a list item without using count or counter?

Tags: python, count

I have a list of words and want to know how many unique words there are. I will eventually import the list into a dictionary showing how many of each word there is.

Right now I have

```
while i < len(list_words): 
    if list_words[i] in list_words:
        repetitions += 1 
    i += 1
print(repetitions)
```

But this just returns the length of the list .

Comment: Can you provide the sample input and the expected output?

Answer (score 3):

Using [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples) with `int`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

l = ['apple','banana','pizza','apple','banana']

d = defaultdict(int)
for k in l:
    d[k] += 1

print(d)
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'apple': 2, 'banana': 2, 'pizza': 1})
```

If you want to know the words which are unique use:

```
keys = list(d.keys())
[keys[index] for index, value in enumerate(d.values()) if value == 1]
['pizza']
```

To get the count of unique words use:

```
sum([True for value in d.values() if value == 1])
1
```

Comment: Sry the downvoting was accidental I made an upvote back. Sry again

Answer (score 3):

try this,

```
    word_counts = dict.fromkeys(list_words, 0)

    for word in list_words:
        word_counts[word] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get it by this formula `length of words list - length of unique words list`, which can be calculated by `len(list_words) - len(set(list_words))`. There is no need to do a loop.

Answer (score 0):

`len` to a `list comprehension`:

```
>>> l = ['apple','banana','pizza','apple','banana']
>>> len([i for i in l if i == 'apple']) # for example we want "apple" to be the one to count.
2
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

One possiblitiy would be this:

```
list_words = ["cat", "mouse", "cat", "rat"]
i = 0
dictionary = {}
result = 0

for unique_word in set(list_words):

    word_occurances = 0

    for word in list_words:
        if word == unique_word:
            word_occurances += 1

    dictionary[unique_word] = word_occurances

for word in dictionary:
    if dictionary[word] == 1:
        result += 1  

print("There are " + str(result) + " unique words")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for python 2.7

```
    list_words = ["a","b","c","a","b","b","a"]
    d = {}
    for word in list_words:
        if word in d.keys():
            d[word]+=1
        else:
            d[word]=1

    print "There are %d different words and they are: %s"%(len(d.keys()), d.keys())
    print d
```

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATED:**

```
ls = ["apple", "bear", "cat", "cat", "drive"]
lu = set(ls)

d = {}
for s in ls:
    if s in d.keys():
        d[s] += 1
    else:
        d[s] = 1

print(d["cat"]) # counts a word in the list
print([s for s in lu if d[s] > 1]) # Multiply values
print(lu) # Unique values
print(d) # Number of unique words
```

**Out:**

```
 2
 ['cat']
 {'cat', 'bear', 'drive', 'apple'}
 {'apple': 1, 'bear': 1, 'cat': 2, 'drive': 1}
```

Comment: this is using a loop, and a very inefficient one.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I updated my answer with another possibility and that is why occurs a loop. Why you find it inefficient argue it.

Comment: It is inefficient because you are calling `.count` in a loop, giving you worst-case quadratic complexity, when you can do this in linear time.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It doesn't  give worst-case quadratic complexity as you wrote, but fact that can be do count() out of the loop. Thanks for the point out.

Comment: Yes, it most certainly does give worst-case quadratic time complexity. In the worst case, all you have all unique items in the list, so `set(mylist)` gives you `N` items, and then you call `.count` N times, which has to iterate over `N` items each time. Thus, O(N**2)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I will rethink my opinion but see my update meanwhile. Thank you for your valuable comment

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes it's true the WCQTC and I updated my answer according to it. Thanks btw any other concern with it, for what I could get downvote?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I tested it and it resulted in 3 times time increasing the  particular O(N**2) nominated loop itself, but was independently from the unique words' number.